# Android ant build failing on xxhdpi folder

Tags: java, android, ant

Using my current android tools, I am able to build an android project in Eclipse. When I try to build the same project using ant from the commandline, it fails with the following output:

```
-build-setup:
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...

-pre-build:

-code-gen:
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
[renderscript] No RenderScript files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Found Deleted Target File
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [aapt] invalid resource directory name: /data/project/res/drawable-xxhdpi

BUILD FAILED
/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools/ant/build.xml:485: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools/ant/build.xml:560: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools/ant/build.xml:589: null returned: 1
```

It's my understanding that drawable-xxhdpi is a supported format now, so why is this working in Eclipse but not on ant?

== Edit (Adding my project.properties file) ==
This is what my project.properties file has in it:

```
 android.library.reference.1=resources/
 android.library.reference.2=../promotion
 # Project target.
 target=android-8
 android.library.reference.3=resources/
 android.library.reference.4=resources/
```

Comment: My guess: you have set the wrong sdk target in your ant script. Try android update project and give it the correct target.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Tim. I've run the android update project for both the project and it's library folders to no avail.

Comment: mind showing your project.properties?

Comment: Updated the original post to include my project.properties file.

Answer (score 1):

You have set the wrong sdk target in your ant script/project.properties. SDK Version for Android 4.2 is 17, you compile with SDK Version 8, which is Android 2.2.

Use this to update your project:

android update project --target **correct target**

You can list the available targets with `android list targets`.

Alternatively just update your project.properties and manually set the SDK version to 17 (or whichever android sdk you want to compile with):

```
target=android-17
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your AAPT , I just solve this problem.